# Javascript Outerhtml error in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script for show and hide some html content.my code like this

```
 $(".head-text").live('click', function (event) {

        var header = $(this);
        var listid = header.find('strong').attr("data-id");
        var list = "#" + listid;
        var ajaxManager = $.manageAjax.create('cacheQueue', {
            queue: true,
            cacheResponse: false
        });
        if ($(list).length == 0) {
            $("#ajax-loading-01").show();
            ajaxManager.add({
                type: 'GET', url: '/ajaxhandler', data: { showlist: "1", listid: listid }

             , success: function (data) {

                 header.parent().append($(data).find(list)[0].outerHTML);

                 header.parent()._removeClass('show').addClass('hide');


             }
             , complete: function () {

                 $("#ajax-loading-01").hide();
             }
             , error: function (err) {

             }
            });

            return false;
        }
    });
```

It is nice working in chrome and mozilla, but the `outerHTML` is not working in IE - `header.parent().append($(data).find(list)[0].outerHTML))`. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Why don't you juse use `$(data).find(list)`?

Comment: the html contain 

<p>
<span>.....</span>
<>....</>
.....
....
</p>   I need all the data inside the <p> tag ,so I use outerhtml,but it is not working in IE

Comment: It would also be helpful if you posted your relevant HTML and the response of the AJAX that's in `data`. Also, you have `header.parent()._removeClass('show').addClass('hide');` - did you mean `.removeClass`?

Comment: What exact error are you getting that "`outerHTML` is not working in IE"?

Comment: not for all time some times error show in console

Comment: @lan How can I wrap a div in front of p tag.then I can use the .html.please help.

Comment: How can I add a div tag in front of this data....  $(data).find(list)[0].outerHTML.

Comment: "some times error show in console " what error

Comment: @lan  SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'outerHTML' of undefined or null reference  ..this is the error

Comment: @QkishorSubedi  after that the error also getting..